# New close reason "Not enough information"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

Folks often ask a question, but fail to supply enough information to answer the question. The asker then fails to respond when prodded for additional details. In this situation it would be nice to be able to close the question as "Not enough information".

While "Unclear what you're asking" may fit in some situations. It doesn't fit well when it's clear what is being asked, but the question simply can't be answered without more information.

Comment: Now this one I can agree with ;)

Answer (score 3):

I have a propensity for allowing almost all questions on this SE but I have gone through a few and marked them closed - even if I had tried to provide an answer - because the author never responded to questions needed to provide a good answer.

We get a lot of regurgitated bland questions that stream through the front page and we also might keep others from asking a similar question.

There needs to be some sort of time stipulation with these though.  I think 30 days is good but it could be shorter.  "Not enough information - 30 days with no author response".

Comment: Trouble is, after 30 days nobody will remember to close it.  If you close it right away, the author is notified.  If they edit in more detail, the question automatically goes into the reopen queue.

Comment: I think if used it should be set at a week.

Comment: Again, putting a time limit on when the question is closed, puts the responsibility on the mods to remember to go back and close the question. *Closed* is not really **Closed** anymore, it's just "*On Hold*". The question is automatically moved to the  *reopen* queue if it's edited.